# Using Linear Mixed Models with two fixed factors and a random factor

Tags: statistical-significance, mixed-model, multiple-comparisons, linear

I am trying to make a Linear Mixed Model with two fixed factors ('ANTS and LABEL') with the ('STATE') as a random factor. Can anyone suggest to me how to proceed with such a model in R or Matlab?

An image of the data file is attached. [image: Sample data file]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `RATE` is the response then in R the model would be:

```
RATE ~ ANTS + LABEL + (1|STATE)
```